# Spring Data PostgreSQL Key already exists error

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data

I have a following PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS levels (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(256),
    created_date timestamp,
    updated_date timestamp
);
```

and corresponding Spring Data entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "levels")
public class Level extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 642499791438799548L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "levels_id_seq", sequenceName = "levels_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "levels_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

...
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private Date updatedDate;

    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() {
        setCreatedDate(new Date());
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void onPersist() {
        setUpdatedDate(new Date());
    }

...
}
```

this is my Spring Data Level Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface LevelRepository extends JpaRepository<Level, Integer> {

    Level findByName(String name);

}
```

Right now when I try to save a new Level entity with Spring LevelRepository I receive a following error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key violates unique constraint « levels_pkey »
DETAIL: Key "(id)=(5)" already exists.
```

What can be wrong with my configuration ?

Comment: Have you tried `strategy=GenerationType.AUTO`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an entry in your db, already with an ID=5?

Comment: I already have entity with ID=5 in my db.. but I think it should be smart enough in order to generate new non existent ID... but anyway I can be wrong because I'm new with PostgreSQL

Comment: @gonzo, AUTO works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strategy=GenerationType.AUTO` instead and you should be good. `strategy=GenerationType.AUTO` will use a table to generate the ID's instead of using a sequence.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to leave your `GenerationType` instead of using `GenarationType.AUTO` [from that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872214/8877698)

and the error occurs probably cause of hardcoded inserts in data.sql file.

Insert using defined sequence in the entity

```sql
INSERT INTO levels(id, name) VALUES (nextval('levels_id_seq'), 'test');
```

the same way with `GenerationType.IDENTITY` it will create the sequence "%Your-table-name%_id_seq".

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm upgrading to Hibernate 5 and somehow tests were failing. All of the code we have looked correct and nowhere did I find a similar answer like yours!